# Complex Harmonic Function Definition

Tags: complex-analysis

A function $z=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ that satisfies Cauchy–Riemann equations also satisfies $\Delta u=0$ and $\Delta v=0$.

We say a function is harmonic if both $\Delta u=0$ and $\Delta v=0$? or because $\Delta u=0\iff \Delta v=0$ we can say that a function is harmonic if $\Delta v=0$?

Comment: The fact that $\Delta u=0 \iff \Delta v=0$ is true only if it is known a priori that $u+iv$ is holomorphic. Otherwise, it needs not be true, as $u$ and $v$ might be completely unrelated.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, I meant that we know $f$ holomorphic, but thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $u$ is called harmonic if $\Delta u=0$. That's all there is to it.

If $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic on a region, $u$ and $v$ are harmonic, and we also have $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v=0$. Harmonic $u$ and $v$ satisfying this condition are called *harmonic conjugates*.

To go the other way, given harmonic $u,v : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^2 $ satisfying $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v=0$,
$$u\left(\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2},\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}\right)+iv\left(\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2},\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}\right)$$
is analytic on the interior of $U$.